# Applying a macro to all files under a folder

Tags: recursion, vim, macros

I am using gvim 7.4 on Windows.

I have a macro recorded that I want to apply on specific files (for example, *.sql) under a parent directory. If I open the file and press @q, the macro works perfectly fine.

Is there a way I can recursively search for all .sql files and apply the macro? I can do this manually by opening the individual files but I wanted to see if I could use a "search and apply macro" method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are `bufdo` and `argdo` commands. At least you can trigger your macro in `normal` command.

something like:

```
:bufdo exe 'norm! @q' |w
```

give it a try.

**Note**, this will save the file after the macro is played.

Comment: The problem is how to get the list of files into the buffers. It's w32, bashism `**/*.sql` doesn't work in the command line. The files must be loaded from `vim`.

Comment: Thank you. I used argo.

Comment: @phd wouldnt :find be a somewhat portable way around that?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Almost. It shouldn't be `:find` but something like `args **/*.sql` or `:edit **/*.sql`. It'd nice to have it in the answer. The answer then will be more complete.